# Абстрактный синглтон класс

Tags: php, ооп

Требуется написать абстрактный класс, наследники которого должны быть синглтонами.

Подскажите пожалуйста, насколько это адекватная практика, и какие есть методы реализации?

Comment: Звучит как какая-то муть...

Comment: Адекватная практика - не использовать синглтон. Сервис локатор куда меньшее зло

Comment: А что делать в этом случае? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/973082/абстрактный-класс-с-общим-методом/

Comment: @ArchDemon Синглтон вполне себе полезный шаблон проектирования. Просто надо уметь его готовить и использовать там, где надо. Собственно как и любой другой шаблон проектирования.

Comment: @Qwertiy Например если скрипт работает с несколькими разными БД.