# абстрактный класс с общим методом

Tags: php, ооп

```
abstract class Entity {

    abstract public function getEntityType() : int;

    public function compareHash(array $dataItem) : bool {

        // todo
        // Return big array from data base
        $hashBase = (new HashBase())->getData($this->getEntityType());

    }

}
```

Каждый наследник реализует метод getEntityType, и $hashBase у всех будет свой.
Но надо сделать так, чтобы при каждом вызове метода compareHash для каждого наследника была выборка из БД (т.е. $hashBase).

Наверное нужен singleton ? Илистатическое свойство?

Извиняюсь за свой англ

Comment: Пробовал добавить статическое свойство, `public static $hashBase = null;`
далее проверять: `if(static::$hashBase == null)   static::$hashBase =(new HashBase())->getData($this->getEntityType());`

Но не работает.. Для всех наследников получается одни и те же данные $hashBase

Comment: Статическое свойство одно на всех. Если вам нужно свойство отличающееся в наследниках, то не нужно делать свойство статическим

Comment: Нужно чтобы для каждого наследника был только 1 запрос к БД. Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Где в своём классе вы видите хоть один запрос к БД? Я вот ни одного не вижу

Comment: Комментарий $hashBase - // Return big array from data base

Answer (score -1):

Добавь статическое поле $hashBaseArr, оно будет одно для всех наследников, и в него записывай значения где ключ - это имя класса наследника. 
Примерно вот так:

```
abstract class Entity {
    abstract public function getEntityType() : int;
    public static $hashBaseArr = [];

    public function compareHash(array $dataItem) : bool {
        // todo
        // Return big array from data base
        if ( !isset(static::$hashBaseArr[get_called_class()]) ) {
            static::$hashBaseArr[get_called_class()] = (new HashBase())->getData($this->getEntityType());
        }
    }
}
```